# (JetPack Compose, Android studio) Can't import weight (Error cannot acces Row/ColumnScopeInstance)

Tags: kotlin, import, android-jetpack-compose

To train on this langage in order to build my own app, I am trying to do this exercice :
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems?hl=fr&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%3Fhl%3Dfr%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems#3

But for this I need to make columns and rows that take half the screen size. From what I have understood, I need to use Modifier.weight. But when I try to use it, it says "Unresolved reference: weight". So I click on import, but then this import gets an error:

[Error cannot access RowScopeInstance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQY6n.png)

Am I doing something wrong ?

If you need my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScopeInstance.weight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.leanback.widget.Row
import com.example.quadrantcompose.ui.theme.QuadrantComposeTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            QuadrantComposeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Quadrant()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Case(title: String, description: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    Column(
        Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        Text(
            text = description,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Quadrant(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Case(
            "Text composable",
            "Displays text and follows the recommended Material Design guidelines.",
            modifier.background(Color(0xFFEADDFF))
        )
        Case("Image composable",
            "Creates a composable that lays out and draws a given Painter class object.",
            modifier.background(Color(0xFFD0BCFF))
        )
    }

    /*Row {
        Case("Row composable", "A layout composable that places its children in a horizontal sequence.")
        Case("Column composable", "A layout composable that places its children in a vertical sequence.")
    }*/
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun QuadrantPreview() {
    Quadrant()
}
```

I searched on internet for a solution but I can't find one, either because nobody had the exact same problem or because I don't have enough experience on Android Studio and Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that error occurs when trying to use the `weigth modifier` outside the scope of `Column/Row`.
in your case you are using the `weight modifier` for your `column` but the parent of that `column` is the composable `Case` so it's not a `Row` or `Column`:

```
@Composable
fun Case(title: String, description: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    Column(
        Modifier.weight(1f)
    ) {
      //code
    }
}
```

in addition if you look closely you will see that you are passing a parameter called `Modifier` to your composable but not using it anywhere(in android studio it will appear Gray which indicates that this parameter is not used anywhere and can be removed).

to fix this all you have to do is change your `Case` composable so that its `column` takes the `modifier` that you are passing to it so like this:

```
@Composable
fun Case(title: String, description: String, modifier: modifier = Modifier){
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
      //your code
    }
}
```

Now after changing the `Case` composable you have to pass to it a `modifier` with the intended weight you want it to take when its called:

```
@Composable
fun Quadrant(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Case(
            "Text composable",
            "Displays text and follows the recommended Material Design guidelines.",
            Modifier.weight(1f).background(Color(0xFFEADDFF))
        )
        Case("Image composable",
            "Creates a composable that lays out and draws a given Painter class object.",
            Modifier.weight(1f).background(Color(0xFFD0BCFF))
        )
    }
}
```

**Caution: I changed the `modifier` of each case from `modifier` to `Modifier`**

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer ! It is super clear and I managed to understand the problem and finish the exercice thanks to you ! The only thing I don't really understand is with the modifier/Modifier. Isn't the syntax of an argument : name : type (= default value) ? Because I've written the argument name modifier of a type Modifier I think. So what was the problem ?

Comment: @kasimaru13 I'm it's my fault i thought i saw you write Modifier : Modifier= Modifier with capital M for name totally my mistake your good to go